# mongo-scala-driver: How do i capture both the partial results and the decoding errors in an Observable?

Tags: scala, mongo-scala-driver

Is there a way when working with find operations to capture as values both emerging decoding exceptions and the data ?

When decoding all the retrieved BSONs some may have invalid properties and will not be decodable into domain object.

What i had in mind:

```scala
  val findAsyncResult: Future[List[Either[DecodingExceptions, Data]]] =
      database
        .getCollection[String](???)
        .find(???)
        .toFuture()
}
```

I noticed that when one value can't be decoded the whole operation is failed.
I was hopping i can somehow accumulate errors and valid data.